# Delay on transition when I use sliding-menu - Bad effect (Android)

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm trying to use the Onsen-UI with sliding-menu and when I test on device (Android) I see a delay on transition between pages/navigators.
The previous page appears a little bit until the new page is changed.

Comment: Are you seeing the delay on the Monaca Debugger or a built app? Do test it as a built app.

Comment: Hi, I'm seeing on a built app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the project template provided by Monaca? I am using Android device (2.3), but no such effect appears.